JavaScript error: on button element, click is not a function?
I'm having issues with JavaScript not detecting the click event on a button. Here is my HTML code:
<input type="button" value="Upload"
       id="filemanagement_uploadbutton[0]"
       name="filemanagement_uploadbutton"
       onclick="javascript:uploadFiles();"
       >

Here is my JavaScript code (with console.log commands for error checking):
let fileButtons = document.getElementsByName('filemanagement_uploadbutton');
console.log(fileButtons.length);    // returns 2, since I have two buttons
console.log(fileButtons[0].id);     // returns filemanagement_uploadbutton[0]
console.log(fileButtons[0].type);   // returns button
console.log(fileButtons[0].click);  // returns javascript:uploadFiles();
fileButtons[0].click();

I've also tried:
let fileButton = document.getElementsByName('filemanagement_uploadbutton')[0];
fileButton.click();

Both of these result in the error:

Uncaught TypeError: fileButtons[0].click is not a function

or

Uncaught TypeError: fileButton.click is not a function

How is it telling me that click is not a function on the element that it's telling me the click function is javascript:uploadFiles(); literally one element above?
Edit: I've also tried these variations:
let fileButtons = document.getElementsByName('filemanagement_uploadbutton')[0];   //obviously the command for fileButtons[0].length won't work here as expected, so I comment it out
let fileButton = document.getElementById('filemanagement_uploadbutton[0]');

with the appropriate changes to the code below when I reference them.

The first error I'm getting is Uncaught ReferenceError: uploadFiles is not defined from onclick="javascript:uploadFiles();". Post a [mcve] please

FYI there's no need for javascript: in onXXX attributes. That's only needed when putting JavaScript in href

Can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/wk6qrho9/

I think the specific problem of your code is that .getElementsByName() return a NodeList (in most user agents, except IE and Edge), which is an array of nodes (not elements). And nodes don't have .click() functions... Then, you should access fileButtons[0].nodeValue.click().

@KLASANGUI That's not how nodeValue works. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue

@Barmar, yeah, I'm aware I don't need the javascript: part in HTML, but I keep it in because there have been times I've done a global search on my project for all events (onclick, onchange, on____) and this way, I get a complete list instead of having to search for each on____ individually. Thanks, though!

What does console.log(typeof fileButtons[0].click); show?

It says "string." Is that what we want?

Instead of using the inline HTML "onclick" function, you could try removing it and using an event listener in your JavaScript instead.
let fileButtons = document.getElementByName('filemanagement_uploadbutton');

if (fileButtons.length > 0) {
fileButtons[0].addEventListener('click', uploadFiles);
fileButtons[0].click();
}


Thank you - I edited my response to correct the issue.

Thanks, @DevynJohnson! I tried doing that. No dice. :/ Because I might use the button several times a session, I put a removeEventListener, then your addEventListener:
fileButtons[0].removeEventListener('click', uploadFilesFromFileManagement);
fileButtons[0].addEventListener('click', uploadFilesFromFileManagement);

But I still got the same error on fileButtons[0].click(); (but not the event-listener-related stuff).

You are need to have your code something like this.
First you need get the element by id using document.getElementById('filemanagement_uploadbutton[0]')
and then add the add event listener.
addEventListener('click', () => {
    // your code goes here
});



document.getElementById('filemanagement_uploadbutton[0]').addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert('hi');
});
<button id="filemanagement_uploadbutton[0]" name="filemanagement_uploadbutton">Upload</button>




I think they want to process all the buttons, not just one of them; using [0] is just a simplification for the example. That's why they use getElementsByName() instead of using a specific ID.

@Barmar, either/or is fine. The evolution of the code led me to getElementsByName, but since all the buttons have identical click functions, if I isolate one of them, it's all good. Whichever works. But I've tried both ways, and both give me the same error.
